# Converge of a sequence of sums of Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Assume that we have a sequence of i.i.d. random variables that are Gaussian mean $\mu$, and variance $\sigma^2$. I am trying to study the converge of the following sequence of random variables:

\begin{equation}
S_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=2} \bigg\{X_i \frac{\sum^{i-1}_{j=1}X_j}{i} \bigg\}
\end{equation}

I suspect this might converge to $\mu^2$ but I am not sure how to apply the law of large numbers here, since quantities in the sum are not independent. I would really appreciate if someone could provide a hint. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting expression. I assume you already computed expected values. Also, you have $$nS_n - (n-1)S_{n-1} = X_n\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}X_i/n$$ that might help

Comment: The expected value of the term in the sum should be $ \frac{i-1}(i} \mu^2$.

Comment: $\frac{i-1}{i}\mu^2$ (typo in formula)

Comment: But can you compute the expected value of $S_n$

Comment: Yes. I will try to find where this will converge.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[S_n] $ converges to $\mu^2$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can indeed be treated using the strong law of large numbers. Let $$\Omega':=\left\{\omega\in\Omega,\frac 1i\sum_{l=1}^iX_l\to \mu          \right\}.$$
Then $\Omega'$ has probability one. Let $\omega\in\Omega'$ and fix $\varepsilon\gt 0$. Let $i_0$ be such that for all $i\geqslant i_0$, $\left\lvert \frac 1i\sum_{l=1}^{i-1} X_l(\omega)-\mu\right\rvert\lt\varepsilon  $. Then 
$$S_n(\omega) =\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^{i_0-1} X_i(\omega)\frac{\sum_{l=1}^{i-1} X_l(\omega)}l +\frac 1n\sum_{i=i_0}^{n} X_i(\omega)\left( \frac{\sum_{l=1}^{i-1} X_l(\omega)}l -\mu\right)+\frac\mu  n\sum_{i=i_0}^{n} X_i(\omega).$$
The first term goes to zero, the second one do not exceed $\varepsilon n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\left\lvert X_i\left(\omega\right)\right\rvert$, which goes to $\varepsilon \mathbb E\left\lvert X_1\right\rvert $  by the strong law of large numbers. By the strong law of large numbers, the third term goes to $\mu^2$.